# How to show a message when WinJS listview data source has no items?

Tags: javascript, winjs

Is there a way to handle the ListView (WinJS) in case of data source has zero items? i.e. property or a method to show message

Comment: This was posted a year and a half ago and still has no good response (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503510/how-to-give-a-empty-listview-message-when-there-is-no-data-source)... I honestly am not sure you can do it with a basic `itemTemplate` - you may have to do it entirely custom.

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest thing to do is to just have a `span` or `div` containing your message that you only show when the listview has 0 items.  This is substantially easier to do when using a binding library like [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Example (placed directly below your WinJS listview):

```
<h4 data-bind="visible: (resultDataSource().length === 0)">No Results Found</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with the built in WinJS data-binding

```
<div 
  data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
  data-win-options="{itemDataSource: app.model.items.dataSource}"
  data-win-bind="style.display: app.model.items app.displayBlockIf"
  ></div>
<div data-win-bind="style.display: app.model.items app.displayBlockIfNot">No items.</div>
```

In Code:

```
isSet = function(value) {
  if (!value) {
    return false;
  }
  if (value.length === 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};

WinJS.Namespace.define("app", {
  displayBlockIf: WinJS.Binding.converter(function(value) {
    if isSet(value) then "block" else "none";
  }),

  displayBlockIfNot: WinJS.Binding.converter(function(value) {
    if !isSet(value) then "block" else "none";
  }),

  model: {
    items: new WinJS.Binding.List()
  }

});
```

Then somewhere in your pages `ready()` function:

```
ready: function(element, options) {
  WinJS.Binding.processAll(element, { app: app });
}
```